# multiline regex pattern match

Tags: python, regex

I have the following multiline(?) string that I get from the output of a process.

> 04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from 192.68.10.1    :
>   04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from 192.68.10.1    :
>   TSB1 File Name:                    OCAP_TSB_76 04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE
>   from 192.68.10.1    :                                        TSB1
>   Duration:                   1752 seconds 04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from
>   192.68.10.1    :                                        TSB1 Bit Rate:                      3669 kbps 04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from 192.68.10.1    :
>   04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from 192.68.10.1    :
>   TSB2 File Name:                    OCAP_TSB_80 04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE
>   from 192.68.10.1    :                                        TSB2
>   Duration:                     56 seconds 04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from
>   192.68.10.1    :                                        TSB2 Bit Rate:                      3675 kbps 04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from 192.68.10.1    :

I am trying to extract just the values in 'seconds' and 'kbps'.

This is what I have so far.

```
>>> cpat = re.compile(r"\.*RESPONSE from[^:]+:\s*TSB[\d] Duration:\s*(\d+) seconds\.*?RESPONSE from[^:]+:\s*TSB[\d] Bit Rate:\s*(\d+) kbps", re.DOTALL)
>>> m = re.findall(cpat,txt)
>>> m
[]
```

I find matches if I break the regex into separate parts.
But, I am looking to find matches like below

> > > m
> > >       [(1752,3669),(52,3675)]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
re.compile(r"\.*RESPONSE from[^:]+:\s*TSB[\d] Duration:\s*(\d+) seconds\.*?RESPONSE from[^:]+:\s*TSB[\d] Bit Rate:\s*(\d+) kbps", re.DOTALL)
                                                                       ^
```

I think that this dot was not meant to be escaped (because otherwise, it will be matching literal dots instead of any character. Try with:

```
re.compile(r"\.*RESPONSE from[^:]+:\s*TSB[\d] Duration:\s*(\d+) seconds.*?RESPONSE from[^:]+:\s*TSB[\d] Bit Rate:\s*(\d+) kbps", re.DOTALL)
```

---

Also, there are some unnecessary parts in your regex that you can remove and still ensure the matches you're looking for. I removed them in the below regex:

```
re.compile(r"RESPONSE from[^:]+:\s*TSB\d Duration:\s*(\d+) seconds.*?RESPONSE from[^:]+:\s*TSB\d Bit Rate:\s*(\d+) kbps", re.DOTALL)
```

Namely:

- You don't need `.*` at the start of the regex with `re.findall`.
- You don't need to put `\d` within square brackets if it is alone.

Answer (score 2):

This code gives what you want:

import re

```
data = '''
04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from 192.68.10.1 :
04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from 192.68.10.1 :
TSB1 File Name: OCAP_TSB_76 04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from 192.68.10.1 : TSB1 Duration: 1752 seconds 04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from 192.68.10.1 : TSB1 Bit Rate: 3669 kbps 04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from 192.68.10.1 :
04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from 192.68.10.1 :
TSB2 File Name: OCAP_TSB_80 04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from 192.68.10.1 : TSB2 Duration: 56 seconds 04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from 192.68.10.1 : TSB2 Bit Rate: 3675 kbps 04/18@14:22 - RESPONSE from 192.68.10.1 :
'''

output = []
block_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+\/\d+@\d+:\d+ - RESPONSE.*?)(.*)')
seconds_speed_pattern = re.compile(r'TSB.*Duration:(.*)seconds.*TSB.*Bit Rate:(.*)kbps')
blocks = re.findall(block_pattern, data)
for block in blocks:
    ss_data = re.findall(seconds_speed_pattern, block[1])
    if ss_data:
        output.append(ss_data[0])

print output
```

This prints

```
[(' 1752 ', ' 3669 '), (' 56 ', ' 3675 ')]
```

In order to convert those values from `str` to `int`s just do:

```
output = [(int(a.strip()), int(b.strip())) for a, b  in output]
```

This gives:

```
[(1752, 3669), (56, 3675)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = re.findall(r"(?sim)Duration: (\d+).*?Rate: (\d+)", subject)


Options: dot matches newline; case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match the characters “Duration: ” literally «Duration: »
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d+)»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match any single character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the characters “Rate: ” literally «Rate: »
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(\d+)»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You might get more upvotes that way!